# Can i save the file from ajax XHR Request in ASP.NET MVC ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am using ajaxSubmit in jQuery to preview the images but are i really can save those images.

if yes then can someone show me the code to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if your browser supports [FileReader API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) which is a part of HTML5.

The basic thing you need to do is:

```
    xhr.open("POST", url);    
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data,);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");     
    body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    body += reader.result + "\r\n"; 
    if(xhr.sendAsBinary) {
      // only firefox
      xhr.sendAsBinary(body);
    } else {
      // chrome (as in W3C)
      xhr.send(body);
    }
  };
  //reading file
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

The code may not be 100% correct, but you get the idea.
Your browser should support FileReader API, you can check it on [html5test.com](http://html5test.com)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this [js library](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) for the client upload. The server-side code could look like this:

```
var destination = Path.GetTempFileName(); // you should probably replace this with a directory the IIS Worker Process has write permission to
try {
    Request.Files[0].SaveAs(destination);
    // Save destination to database or wherever
} finally {
    File.Delete(destination);
}
```